# GLSL Error: (0) : error C5145: must write to gl_Position

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, linker-errors

When I go to **link** my compiled vertex and fragment shaders, I get this error:

```
(0) : error C5145: must write to gl_Position
```

Here is the basic section of my code where the error occurs:

```
GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, 1, &vertexShaderCode, nullptr);
glCompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
GLint okay;
glGetShaderiv(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &okay);
if (okay == GL_FALSE) {
    char infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, 512, nullptr, infoLog);
    error("Failed to compile vertex shader.", infoLog);
}

GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, 1, &fragmentShaderCode, nullptr);
glCompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glGetShaderiv(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &okay);
if (okay == GL_FALSE) {
    char infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, 512, nullptr, infoLog);
    error("Failed to compile fragment shader.", infoLog);
}

GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &okay);
if (okay == GL_FALSE) {
    char infoLog[512];
    glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, nullptr, infoLog);
    error("Failed to link the shader program.", infoLog);
}

glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
```

Here is the vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 vertexData;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 textureCoord;
out vec2 textCoord;
uniform mat4 projectionMat;
uniform mat4 viewMat;
uniform mat4 modelMat;
void main() {
    gl_Position = projectionMat * viewMat * modelMat * vec4(vertexData, 1.0f);
    vertColor = vertexColor;
    textCoord = textureCoord;
}
```

Here is the fragment shader (*in case it matters*):

```
#version 330 core
in vec2 textCoord;
out vec4 color;
uniform sampler2D text;
uniform vec4 textColor;
void main() {
    color = texture(text, textCoord) * textColor;
}
```

I did some investigating and toyed around with it and found that (*unlike other people*) the source I was sending to OpenGL was **not** empty and was the full, correct source (*I found this by printing* `vertexShaderCode`).

How do I fix it?

Comment: "*when I got the length of the source*" `glShaderSource` does not *return* the length. That parameter is for you to optionally *provide* a length, just in case you are using strings that aren't NUL terminated (or if you have a string type that has a size, so that the implementation doesn't have to compute it and can save time). You got an arbitrary value "back" because you never *initialized* `length`. And `glShaderSource` didn't modify it.

Comment: Alright, but I only *added* that to error check.  That was not the source of the problem.  I did a little more testing and found that `glGetShaderiv(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &okay);` changed `okay`'s value to `-858993460`.  Also, on a new computer, it is giving me either that the vertex shader isn't compiled or the fragment shader isn't compiled.

Comment: Actually, I just found that it isn't changing `okay`'s value to `-858993460`, it simply **isn't changing it at all**.  Is this some problem on OpenGL's end?

Comment: I just noticed that my perfectly legitimate question got downvoted twice... Can someone please explain this to me?  This seems to happen to me a lot, and I **never** get an explanation.  If I *lose* reputation for asking good questions, why stay on the site?

Comment: "*If I lose reputation for asking good questions, why stay on the site?*" Have you considered that maybe your question is not a good question? The tooltip for the down arrow says "this question does not show any research effort," and it's not an unreasonable assessment of your question. After all, your problem ultimately boils down to you misusing the API in a way that some `glGetError` checking would have at least guided you towards (since using `GL_VERTEX_SHADER` there would have given an `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
> ```

This creates a shader object for a vertex shader. And this means that `vertexShader` now contains that shader object. Given that:

> ```
> glShaderSource(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, 1, &vertexShaderCode, nullptr);
> ```

What does this do? It's supposed to put the given code into a shader object. But none of the parameters *are a shader object*. The first parameter is an OpenGL enumerator, which is not a shader object.

Shader and program objects are not like most OpenGL objects. You don't bind them just to set data into them (except for uniforms and programs, but we don't even need to bind them for that since GL 4.1). If you want to manipulate a shader, you have to actually pass the shader to the function that manipulates it.

> ```
> glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderCode, nullptr);
> ```